# AvalonEditor SearchPanel

Tags: wpf, avalonedit

I use avalonEdit:TextEditor to show XML-Files and want to add the Search-Function using ICSharpCode.AvalonEdit.Search.SearchPanel:

```
SearchPanel sp = new SearchPanel();
sp.Attach(textEditor.TextArea);
sp.Open();
```

It works well, but the text box in the panel does not have focus. The method "Reactivate" doesn't work either.
Can anyone tell me how to set the focus on the text box in SearchPanel?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The Open method inserts the control into the adorner layer of the text editor. You will have to use

```
sp.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, (Action)sp.Reactivate);
```

to trigger the reactivation *after* the SearchPanel instance has been initialized properly. The API is kind of messy and sure needs some clean-up, but this should solve your problem for now.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I found another way to activate the find function:

`xmlEditor.TextArea.DefaultInputHandler.NestedInputHandlers.Add(new SearchInputHandler(xmlEditor.TextArea));`

Answer (score 0):

As Siegfried suggested, In VB.Net I have used

```
searchPanel.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(Sub() searchPanel.Reactivate(), Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input)
```

and it worked great.